# Convert Date Format in Update Query

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to perform and update query that updates the date in a database. Please note, I'm using a version of SQL Server older than 2008 so I cannot use the Date type.

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET TABLE.DATECOLUMN = @input_date
```

I'm trying to do something like below, I want the date entered to essentially get rid of the time in datetime, so set it to midnight.

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, TABLE.DATECOLUMN)) = @input_date
```

Comment: Slight detour...using the shortcuts for date parts is a challenge because they are difficult to remember. https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET DATECOLUMN = CONVERT(DATETIME, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @input_date))
```